# Error open files after creating ~/.vimrc

Tags: vim

Before today I was using `/etc/vim/vimrc` to configure my vim setup. Today I thought of creating `.vimrc` file. So, I used

```
touch .vimrc
cat /etc/vim/vimrc > .vimrc
```

So, now when I open any file with vim I get the following errors:

```
Error detected while processing /home/ronnie/.vimrc:
line   68:
E122: Function SplitColors already exists, add ! to replace it
line   77:
E122: Function ChangeColors already exists, add ! to replace it
line  171:
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
line  174:
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I have both `/etc/vim/vimrc` and `.vimrc` file located in my system. So, is this the reason I am getting this error because from now on I would like to use only `.vimrc` to configure my vim setup.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're defining functions that have the same name as some already defined. Adding an exclamation mark after `function` "overwrites" the previous definition, and in your case will stop the error message from showing.

Answer (score 6):

This is the solution by example since most of the answers are correct above but they don't directly help you solve the problem. Areas of interest in bold.

" code with redefinition issues

> **function** CloseDuplicateTabs() endfunction
>
> **command** CloseDupTabs :call CloseDuplicateTabs()

" fixed code with overrides

> **function!** CloseDuplicateTabs() endfunction
>
> **command!** CloseDupTabs :call CloseDuplicateTabs()

Answer (score 4):

Why not add ! to your function definitions as suggested? it will make vim stop complaining.

Alternatively you could remove those definition from /etc/vim/vimrc

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that both `/etc/vim/vimrc` and `.vimrc` are sourced. This depends on several factors; see the details at `:help .vimrc`.

In general, the system-wide Vim config should reside in the former file, and your personal customizations in the latter. For single-user systems, there isn't much of a difference, but you did the right thing in moving the stuff into your home directory. Just delete the duplicate functions etc. from the former file, or remove it completely if you've moved everything to your `.vimrc`.

Comment: This is the real answer ... Solution : just put contents of ~/.vimrc  into /etc/vim/vimrc  and remove from ~/.vimrc  ... Done

Comment: @ScottStensland: That's pragmatic, but not correct. System and personal config should be kept separate, if just to avoid work or data loss at system updates.